# Can someone help me debug my python program?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So whenever i run this program i get a syntax error that says the following:
 File "dice.py", line 17
    def dice(diceAmount):
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Here is the program:

```
# dice.py
# written for python 3.4
# by Will Jones

import os
import platform
import random

opSys = platform.system()

if opSys == "Windows":
    system.os("cls")
else:
    system.os("clear")

print("This program gives you a number based on 1 or more dice rolls\n")
diceAmount = eval(input("Enter an amount of dice to roll")

def dice(diceAmount):

    rolls = diceAmount

    while rolls > 0
        rolls = rolls - 1
        dieRoll = random.randint(0,6)
        sum = 0 + dieRoll
        print("The number is:", sum)

def main():

    pie = 4
    dice(diceAmount)
    input("Enter any key to quit")
    system.os("exit")

main()
```

I am pulling my hair out wondering why it won't let me define a damn function. Ugh... So alas i come to you in seek of help.

Comment: "Can someone help me debug my python-program?" does not at all summarize your problem. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a parenthesis

```
diceAmount = eval(input("Enter an amount of dice to roll")
```

should be

```
diceAmount = eval(input("Enter an amount of dice to roll"))
```

Furthermore, you're missing a colon in your while loop

```
while rolls > 0
```

should be

```
while rolls > 0:
```

Comment: Thanks, you are a lifesaver. I hope i don't seem like an idiot for making such careless mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with David, but I would not have kept the eval(). That argument is for another day.

Now whenever you get any sort of syntax error like this, you should work backwards in the code to evaluate the last piece of non-whitespace that would have been scanned.

A good C programmer does this as second nature, and sometimes it is in an included file, sometimes there are pages of comments in between.

This is because the line number generally reflects the compiler/interpreter objection to an unfinished or improper construct on previous lines. It "thinks" your function definition is part of the previous statement. It has had to read a "good" line to know that the previous line is incomplete.

A good LSE should match braces. Notepad++ does this dynamically so it is a passive indicator.

Is this your homework ?   Importing os and using system.os() (sic) rather than os.system() seems like a tutorial assignment.

Don't be discouraged from posting here, everybody starts somewhere.

Comment: Ya i messed up there as well. No it's not homework, but an exercise from a programming book i got. I'm still a noob :-/

Comment: All good, see my minor updates. The more people that try python, the more it will stick. Don't mind the admins - they have their rules. From time to time this type of question will uncover a genuine bug. But bust a real gut yourself first - it builds character.

Comment: thanks mckenzm. That makes me feel a lot better about asking.